# libgit2: Merge with conflicts

Tags: libgit2

I'm working on implementing merge using libgit2, and I'm having trouble getting it to deal with conflicts (changes to the same line in a file) - the merge just aborts, with nothing written to the index or to the workspace. Resolvable conflicts (changes to different lines) are working fine.

It exits with `GIT_ECONFLICT`, which apparently indicates that the worktree and/or index aren't clean, but I checked with `git status` just before calling `git_merge()` and it's clean.

I'm using default merge options, and checkout options set to `GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE | GIT_CHECKOUT_ALLOW_CONFLICTS`. I tried using `FORCE` instead of `SAFE` but it didn't help. What else do I need to do so the conflicts are recorded?

Code is here (in Swift):
https://github.com/Uncommon/Xit/blob/ff1bf6312bb1250b1db432035947a282a2cdd362/Xit/XTRepository%2BMergePushPull.swift#L154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was that, since my unit test had just done a `git commit` using the command line tool, libgit2's in-memory copy of the index was out of date, so using that old copy of the index it thought there was a conflict. Reloading the index with `git_index_read()` before calling `git_merge()` solved the problem.

This is actually a bug in libgit2; `git_merge` should be reloading the index itself: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/4203